# Handle visible cells in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Worksheet named 'Abschluss'. In this worksheet I use filter to get the data-range I want to handle with my vba script. So i only want to handle the visible rows.
My vba Script looks like

```
For Each i In Worksheets("Abschluss").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows
    If (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B2:B" & i), Cells(i, 2)) = 1) Then _
        Umsetzung_Kapitel_1.AddItem Cells(i, 2)
Next
```

This doesn't work, I get runtime-error 438. Do you know where the problem is?
I assume that `Worksheets("Abschluss").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows` returns the wrong data-type, but I couldn't fix it.

Comment: Try declaring i as a long, and doing a `For i = 1 to Worksheets("Abschluss").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count`

Comment: I'm afraid thats not the solution. The Problem is, that when I filter some data, I get for example the row-numbers 2,5,200 and 202.
So `Worksheets("Abschluss").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count` would return `4` an the for-loop would go through row-numbers 1 to 4, but it should go through 2,5,200 and 202. Thats the reason why I used a for-each loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to populate a combobox or a listbox with unique items, possibly in a UserForm?

Try this

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim cUnique As Collection
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim vNum As Variant

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Abschluss")
    Rws = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = sh.Range(sh.Cells(2, 2), sh.Cells(Rws, 2)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    Set cUnique = New Collection

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each Cell In Rng.Cells
        cUnique.Add Cell.Value, CStr(Cell.Value)
    Next Cell
    On Error GoTo 0

    For Each vNum In cUnique
        ComboBox1.AddItem vNum
    Next vNum


End Sub
```

Comment: perfectly. and big thanks. that works great!
ps: yes, i was trying to populate a combobox :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
Dim i As Long
Dim colCount As Long: colCount = Worksheets("Abschluss").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
For i = 1 to colCount
....
```

Comment: I believe you need to add a range in there.  Something like `Worksheets("Abschluss").Range("A:P").SpecialCells..`.  (assuming data spans from columns A:P).  I would also consider starting `i` at 2 in case there are headers that need to be taken into account.

Comment: I'm afraid thats not the solution. The Problem is, that when I filter some data, I get for example the row-numbers 2,5,200 and 202.
So `Worksheets("Abschluss").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count` would return `4` an the for-loop would go through row-numbers 1 to 4, but it should go through 2,5,200 and 202. Thats the reason why I used a for-each loop.